# Jenkins agent failing after upgrade to its docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

I am using docker cloud configuration for my jenkins agents (spins up docker containers for my builds on a given VM). I recently built a new jenkins agent docker image with an updated version of nodejs. The only thing I changed about the docker image was adding a newer version of nodejs

```
ENV NPM_16_VER 16.20.1
```

where I used to just have

```
ENV NPM_8_VER 8.17.0
```

And am adding some lines to install it along with the existing version

```
RUN . "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh" && \
    nvm install ${NPM_8_VER} && \
    nvm install ${NPM_16_VER}
USER root
```

When I change my docker cloud config to pull this image instead of the old one I get the below on the job logs

```
Still waiting to schedule task
All nodes of label 'docker-agent11-test' are offline
```

The agents come up on my VM however (I set to a max of 2)

```
acf5d4b1cb32   repo.domain.com/jnlp-builder-java11:5.1.2   "entry.sh /bin/sh"   38 seconds ago   Up 29 seconds             busy_rhodes
221d45aeaf2f   repo.domain.com/jnlp-builder-java11:5.1.2   "entry.sh /bin/sh"   58 seconds ago   Up 57 seconds             quizzical_yalow
```

The jenkins logs on the agent show the below

```
Connecting to docker container 221d45aeaf2f6b094f2aa7522d753180a723c4be920e0d77bbb50d05025006e8, running command java -jar //remoting-4.12.jar -noReconnect -noKeepAlive -agentLog //agent.log
HTTP/1.1 101 UPGRADED
Content-Type: application/vnd.docker.raw-stream
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: tcp
Api-Version: 1.43
Docker-Experimental: false
Ostype: linux
Server: Docker/24.0.2 (linux)
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching an agent. This is probably a bug in Jenkins
Also:   java.lang.Throwable: launched here
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer._connect(SlaveComputer.java:286)
    at hudson.model.Computer.connect(Computer.java:443)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.strategy.DockerOnceRetentionStrategy.start(DockerOnceRetentionStrategy.java:146)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.strategy.DockerOnceRetentionStrategy.start(DockerOnceRetentionStrategy.java:51)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.createNewComputerForNode(AbstractCIBase.java:180)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.updateNewComputer(AbstractCIBase.java:222)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.updateNewComputer(Jenkins.java:1664)
    at jenkins.model.Nodes.addNode(Nodes.java:144)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.addNode(Jenkins.java:2206)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud.robustlyAddNodeToJenkins(DockerCloud.java:446)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud.access$000(DockerCloud.java:68)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$1.run(DockerCloud.java:382)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
```

Not sure why but it looks like jenkins is able to provision the agent okay but the agent isnt able to communicate back to the jenkins server